# Is this query race condition free?

Tags: sql, race-condition

Let's presume that we have a `t1` table where the integer `weight` column is marked as unique, `item_id` is the primary key. Can the following query fail?

```
UPDATE t1
  SET weight = SELECT new_weight FROM (
    SELECT MAX(weight) + 1 AS new_weight FROM t1
  ) qs
WHERE item_id = ?
```

where `?` is an argument. Is it possible that due a race two items would attempt to set the same weight? Or is that database engine specific?

Comment: This is dependant both on the database engine, and on the isolation level being used (if applicable).

Comment: If your DBMS supports sequences, or autonumbers, or identity columns, you should use these instead. Otherwise, your only safe bet for multiple users is to serialize access to the table i.e. LOCK the table for your transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get two identical weight values due to a race condition. Switch to `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` to avoid this (you will likely get a deadlock instead which you can retry. You avoid any data corruption though). Or employ proper pessimistic locking which is RDBMS specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if two transactions are executed in parallel.

Both transactions will get the same value for `MAX(weight)+1`, and then try to update with this same value, causing a constraint violation.